# Jquery Jeditable Codeigniter sends multiple values

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, jeditable

I have an ID that is Databases ID of the row I want to update, then is the new value that is submited, when pressing enter. What I want to do is assign the database cell which needs to be updated as a rel value. At the moment it only submits db_cell_1 no matter which cell I press to edit. If I press the second cell in my html page, I want it to submit db_cell_2 I hope that I made myself clear about the problem I'm facing. Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<td  id="<?echo $value['ID'];?>" class="merv_editable" rel="db_cell_1" style="text-align: left;" > <?echo $value['nom_nosauk'];?></td>
<td id="<?echo $value['ID'];?>" class="merv_editable" rel="db_cell_2"><?echo $value['merv'];?></td>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.merv_editable').click(function(){

  var attrval = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('.merv_editable').editable('http://www.draugiem.lv',{
        id   : 'elementid',
        name : 'newvalue',
        submitdata : {pzid : attrval}
    });
});
```

Comment: on your 3rd line, change  `$('.merv_editable').editable(` to  `$(this).editable(`

Comment: Awesome it worked, thank you so much! Write it as answer so i can accept it!

Comment: glad it worked, full answer supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to using the class as the invoker of the `editable` call.  Since you are already inside one instance of potentially many from a class (from the click event is of a single element) you have scope of `$(this)` which references just the singular element that was clicked.  You can then pass this element to the editable call to invoke the correct element, not just the first one in source code.

To rectify, the code simply needs to reference the currently invoked element, which is shortcut with the `$(this)` directive.

```
$('.merv_editable').click(function(){
      var attrval = $(this).attr('rel');

    $(this).editable('http://www.draugiem.lv',{
        id   : 'elementid',
        name : 'newvalue',
        submitdata : {pzid : attrval}
    });
});
```